# How to implement level based logging in golang?

Tags: logging, go

Is there any good wrapper available for level based logging in golang?
If not, how should I go about implementing one myself?

What I want is pretty simple. I want a few functions e.g.

```
log.Error()
log.Info()
```

etc that display their outputs to stdout as well as save these in a log file (based on the level given to the program as commandline argument).
How do I implement this wrapper?

Comment: https://github.com/jcelliott/lumber

Comment: There is https://github.com/golang/glog which is probably more than you need but worth looking at. The implementation has a very interesting use of boolean types with methods.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Some more suggestions, now that the existing answers are quite old:

- https://github.com/op/go-logging - smaller than the other here
- https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus - used in many popular projects such as Docker
- https://github.com/inconshreveable/log15
- https://github.com/golang/glog - from Google, implementation of their C++ glog library in Go
- https://github.com/go-kit/kit/tree/master/log focused on "structured logging" which is better for tools to consume
- https://github.com/uber-go/zap - "blazing fast"
- https://github.com/rs/zerolog - zero-allocation JSON logger

Comment: Also  https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap and binary logs https://github.com/ScottMansfield/nanolog https://github.com/larytet/binlog

Comment: nanolog does not meet the "display their outputs to stdout" requirement. Binlog has zero GitHub stars.

Comment: A little update from Dec. 2021, zerolog is one hell of an impressive framework https://github.com/rs/zerolog . A nice alternative to zap.

Comment: In 2023 today, Go 1.21 comes with the standard `log/slog` package. No external library is needed anymore for average users. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76867161/8776746) for the detail.

Answer (score 27):

In 2023 today, Go 1.21.0 finally comes with a standard level logger: [`log/slog` package](https://pkg.go.dev/log/slog#Debug).

No external library is needed anymore for average users.

### 1. Basic Usage

```golang
package main

import "log/slog"

func main() {
    slog.Info("hello")
    slog.Warn("hello")
    slog.Error("hello")
}
```

```
2023/08/09 20:05:49 INFO hello
2023/08/09 20:05:49 WARN hello
2023/08/09 20:05:49 ERROR hello
```

### 1.1 Enable `Debug` Log Level

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/fjUelDMm5qt)

`Debug` log level is disabled by default. To enable it, call [`SetLogLoggerLevel()`](https://pkg.go.dev/log/slog#SetLogLoggerLevel) (available in Go 1.22 or later):

```golang
slog.SetLogLoggerLevel(slog.LevelDebug)
```

### 1.2 Disable Logging

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Hg-NMKJcaMA)

If you want (temporarily) to disable logging, the cleanest solution is to define your own logger (see *4. Create Your Own Logger* for the details).

However, this hacky one-liner works:

```golang
slog.SetLogLoggerLevel(math.MaxInt)
```

### 2. Add Context

The name *slog* is short for *structured logging*, meaning each log entry can have a structure.

The log functions can optionally receive any number of key-value pairs:

```golang
package main

import "log/slog"

func main() {
    slog.Info("hello", "username", "Mike", "age", 18)
}
```

```
2023/08/09 20:07:51 INFO hello username=Mike age=18
```

### 3. Customize Format

[`log` package](https://pkg.go.dev/log) can be used to customize the format of `log/slog` logger.

```golang
package main

import "log"
import "log/slog"

func main() {
    slog.Info("hello")
    log.SetFlags(log.Ldate | log.Lmicroseconds)
    slog.Info("hello")
}
```

```
2023/08/09 20:15:36 INFO hello
2023/08/09 20:15:36.601583 INFO hello
```

### 4. Create Your Own Logger

Basic usage is covered by the top-level functions (e.g. `slog.Info()`) but you can create your own logger for detailed customization.

A created logger can be set as the default logger via `slog.SetDefault()`. After that, the top-level functions (e.g. `slog.Info()`) use your logger.

#### 4.1 Standard Loggers

Constructors are provided in `log/slog` package for some built-in loggers.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log/slog"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    //text logger
    {
        //The second argument enables `Debug` log level.
        handler := slog.NewTextHandler(os.Stderr, &slog.HandlerOptions{Level: slog.LevelDebug})
        slog.SetDefault(slog.New(handler))

        slog.Debug("hello", "username", "Mike", "age", 18)
    }

    //JSON logger
    {
        handler := slog.NewJSONHandler(os.Stderr, &slog.HandlerOptions{Level: slog.LevelDebug})
        slog.SetDefault(slog.New(handler))

        slog.Debug("hello", "username", "Mike", "age", 18)
    }
}
```

```
time=2023-08-09T20:31:05.798+09:00 level=DEBUG msg=hello username=Mike age=18
{"time":"2023-08-09T20:31:05.798984192+09:00","level":"DEBUG","msg":"hello","username":"Mike","age":18}
```

#### 4.2 User-Defined Loggers

By implementing [`Handler`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slog#Handler) interface, you can create a fully-customized logger.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log/slog"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type MyHandler struct{}

func (h MyHandler) Enabled(context context.Context, level slog.Level) bool {
    switch level {
    case slog.LevelDebug:
        return false
    case slog.LevelInfo:
        fallthrough
    case slog.LevelWarn:
        fallthrough
    case slog.LevelError:
        return true
    default:
        panic("unreachable")
    }
}

func (h MyHandler) Handle(context context.Context, record slog.Record) error {
    message := record.Message

    //appends each attribute to the message
    //An attribute is of the form `<key>=<value>` and specified as in `slog.Error(<message>, <key>, <value>, ...)`.
    record.Attrs(func(attr slog.Attr) bool {
        message += fmt.Sprintf(" %v", attr)
        return true
    })

    timestamp := record.Time.Format(time.RFC3339)

    switch record.Level {
    case slog.LevelDebug:
        fallthrough
    case slog.LevelInfo:
        fallthrough
    case slog.LevelWarn:
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "[%v] %v %v\n", record.Level, timestamp, message)
    case slog.LevelError:
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "!!!ERROR!!! %v %v\n", timestamp, message)
    default:
        panic("unreachable")
    }

    return nil
}

// for advanced users
func (h MyHandler) WithAttrs(attrs []slog.Attr) slog.Handler {
    panic("unimplemented")
}

// for advanced users
func (h MyHandler) WithGroup(name string) slog.Handler {
    panic("unimplemented")
}

func main() {
    logger := slog.New(MyHandler{})
    slog.SetDefault(logger)

    slog.Debug("hello") //=> does nothing (as `Enabled()` returns `false`)
    slog.Info("hello")  //=> [INFO] 2023-11-15T22:38:54+09:00 hello
    slog.Warn("hello")  //=> [WARN] 2023-11-15T22:38:54+09:00 hello
    slog.Error("hello") //=> !!!ERROR!!! 2023-11-15T22:38:54+09:00 hello

    //with attributes
    slog.Error("hello", "id", 5, "foo", "bar") //=> !!!ERROR!!! 2023-11-15T22:38:54+09:00 hello id=5 foo=bar

}
```

As the type of the log levels is defined as [`type Level int`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slog#Level), you can even define your own log levels: [The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ZG06erZhMfL)

Comment: Could you add an example of how to print complex types like maps while in debug level?

Comment: @tuxErrante How to enable the debug level is explained in the answer: see *1.1 Enable Debug Log Level* or *4.2 User-Defined Loggers*. In Go, pretty-print is another harder problem. See [*How to pretty print variables - Stack Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27117896/how-to-pretty-print-variables) and use any method you want with *4.2 User-Defined Loggers* in my answer. Personally I like [`pp` package](https://github.com/k0kubun/pp): `pp.Println(yourMap)`.

Comment: Thanks indeed my issue was the positioning of the args in slog call and the printing of a complex map from there, I'm working on something similar to what you've linked me, but trying avoiding extra pkgs also because I'm not working with JSON here: https://goplay.tools/snippet/UcRUpWhPS8m

Answer (score 6):

- [Uber-go/Zap](https://github.com/uber-go/zap): Fast, structured, leveled logging in Go
- [Logrus](https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus): Structured, pluggable logging for Go. (JSON and text formatting)

Both libraries have level hooks also, which is a very interesting feature. Hooks can be registered for particular log levels. So for example any error(logged using `log.Error()`) occurs you can report to some monitoring tool etc.

Comment: one drawback of logrus is that it does n't have log rotation, need to use some external programs for that...

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/hashicorp/logutils  I found this to be very easy to use and you don't even need to change the method calls to `log.Printf` of the std library.

Comment: "The simplest thing that could possibly work" +1

Answer (score 4):

I think [seelog](https://github.com/cihub/seelog) fits your [requirements](https://github.com/cihub/seelog/wiki/Log-levels), and it seems to be pretty popular as it pops up often in log discussions. I never used it seriously, so I can't comment beyond that.

Comment: It looks as though seelog must acquire/release a global lock for each statement.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://cgl.tideland.biz and there at the package "applog". It's working that way.

PS: The whole CGL is currently reworked and will soon be released with new features, but under a different name. ;)

Comment: unfortunately the links are dead

Comment: All the links are dead or don't have anything to do with logging.

Comment: Sorry for all the movements over time. Needed some time to find the current one as the IMHO best one.

The packages are at https://github.com/tideland/golib and the documentation at https://godoc.org/?q=tideland%2Fgolib.

Answer (score 2):

[stdlog](http://godoc.org/github.com/alexcesaro/log/stdlog) fits exactly your requirements:

```
log := stdlog.GetFromFlags()
log.Info("Connecting to the server...")
log.Errorf("Connection failed: %q", err)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with [rlog](https://github.com/romana/rlog) at the moment and like their approach. The code looks good, simplistic and sufficiently documented.

What convinced me:

- no external dependencies
- i can use `rlog.Info()` anywhere without passing around references
- good usage of environment variables
- arbitrary number of trace levels e.g. `rlog.Trace(4, "foo")`

Answer (score 1):

I have added logging level support to the built-in Go log package. You can find my code here:

https://github.com/gologme/log

In addition to adding support for Info, Warn, and Debug, users can also define their own arbitrary logging levels.  Logging levels are enabled and disabled individually. This means you can turn on Debug logs without also getting everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module midlog to implements any other log library,
https://github.com/lingdor/midlog

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

One of the logging module that you can consider is klog . It support 'V' logging which gives the flexibility to log at certain level

klog is a fork of glog and overcomes following drawbacks

glog presents a lot "gotchas" and introduces challenges in containerized environments, all of which aren't well documented.
glog doesn't provide an easy way to test logs, which detracts from the stability of software using it
glog is C++ based and klog is a pure golang implementation

**Sample Implementation**

```
package main

import (
    "flag"

    "k8s.io/klog"


)

type myError struct {
    str string
}

func (e myError) Error() string {
    return e.str
}

func main() {
    klog.InitFlags(nil)
    flag.Set("v", "1")
    flag.Parse()

    klog.Info("hello", "val1", 1, "val2", map[string]int{"k": 1})
    klog.V(3).Info("nice to meet you")
    klog.Error(nil, "uh oh", "trouble", true, "reasons", []float64{0.1, 0.11, 3.14})
    klog.Error(myError{"an error occurred"}, "goodbye", "code", -1)
    klog.Flush()
}
```