# How to pretty print variables

Tags: go, pretty-print

Is there something like Ruby's `awesome_print` in Go?

For example in Ruby you could write:

```
require 'ap'
x = {a:1,b:2} // also works for class
ap x
```

the output would be:

```
{ 
  "a" => 1,
  "b" => 2
}
```

closest thing that I could found is `Printf("%#v", x)`

Comment: If an external package is acceptable, consider [pretty](http://godoc.org/github.com/kr/pretty#example-package).

Comment: I like [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew).

Comment: I tried both go-spew and pretty and found that pretty loses prettiness after some depth of nested structs while go-spew keeps it.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

If your goal is to avoid importing a third-party package, your other option is to use [json.MarshalIndent](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent):

```
x := map[string]interface{}{"a": 1, "b": 2}
b, err := json.MarshalIndent(x, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error:", err)
}
fmt.Print(string(b))
```

Output:

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
}
```

Working sample: http://play.golang.org/p/SNdn7DsBjy

Comment: Testing multiple levels of indention. https://play.golang.org/p/d3nO4Rht90

Comment: Marshal gets intro trouble when there is a custom struct (unsupported type error).  Any easy way to fix that?

Comment: @etang You would have to show a simple example for me to give you a better answer (perhaps in the Playground?). I imagine you'll have to implement one of the JSON package interfaces for unmarshalling your type if it becomes complex.

Answer (score 28):

Nevermind, I found one: https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew

```
// import "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
x := map[string]interface{}{"a":1,"b":2}
spew.Dump(x)
```

Would give an output:

```
(map[string]interface {}) (len=2) {
 (string) (len=1) "a": (int) 1,
 (string) (len=1) "b": (int) 2
}
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want pretty coloured output, you can use `pp`.

https://github.com/k0kubun/pp

```golang
import "github.com/k0kubun/pp"
...
pp.Print(m)
```

[image: pp preview]

Comment: good one for pretty print

Answer (score 4):

I just wrote a simple function based on Simons answer:

```
func dump(data interface{}){
    b,_:=json.MarshalIndent(data, "", "  ")
    fmt.Print(string(b))
}
```

Comment: I do this all the time, +1.  though I usually panic on the error

Answer (score 3):

I came up to use snippet like this:

```
func printMap(m map[string]string) {
    var maxLenKey int
    for k, _ := range m {
        if len(k) > maxLenKey {
            maxLenKey = len(k)
        }
    }

    for k, v := range m {
        fmt.Println(k + ": " + strings.Repeat(" ", maxLenKey - len(k)) + v)
    }
}
```

The output will be like this:

```
short_key:       value1
really_long_key: value2
```

Tell me, if there's some simpler way to do the same alignment.

Comment: You can use `fmt.Printf("%*s: %s", maxLenKey, k, v)` to avoid the `strings.Repeat` call and all that concatenation.